# How to pass Rails variable to AJAX response function?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In AJAX I write:

```
$.ajax({
   URL: '/new_avatar',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { username: 'alizade' },
   success: function(response){
       alert(response);
   },
 })
```

Route.rb:

```
post '/new_avatar' => 'avatars#new_avatar'
```

Avatar.rb model:

```
self.new_avatar(username)
    Avatar.where(username: username).select('avatar').last
end
```

Avatars_Controller:

```
def new_avatar
    @username = params[:username]
    @result = Avatar.new_avatar(@username)
end
```

So, how can send @result to AJAX response function and alert the database selection result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need only response from this service, you can use following way to get the result.

```
def new_avatar
   @username = params[:username]
   render :json => Avatar.new_avatar(@username)
end
```

Comment: And will I get the answer in alert? Now I get html code with empty body part. I do not know why

Comment: you should get created avatar in alert.

Comment: No, I want to get path of the avatar from the database table column avatar

Comment: Did you mean 'path' by column name 'path' in avatar database table, or rails avatar path

Comment: No, its just the record in the database table 'avatar' column.

Your code (render json) returns null

Comment: Do you have the avatar in your database ? If it returns null, this means  Avatar.new_avatar(@username) is null

Comment: But it's not null, I checked it in console

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `render :text` in your controller method

```
def new_avatar
    @username = params[:username]
    @result = Avatar.new_avatar(@username)
    render :text => "#{@username} has this result:- #{@result.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: Now in response I get html page code with empty body part. How can I fix it? Will your answer fix it?